# JAX-RS ExceptionMapper catches all except 401

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly

I wrote a simple custom `ExceptionMapper` for providing a nice response in case of an uncaught exception:

```java
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof WebApplicationException) {
            WebApplicationException webEx = (WebApplicationException)t;
            return webEx.getResponse();
        } else {
            return ResponseHelper.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
    }

}
```

That´s working perfect and all exceptions (404, 415, ...) are caught here except the 401. I also get no response code in my REST client only a plain text response: `Authentication Failed`.

My intention is to return a proper response and also remove the `WWW-Authenticate` which is somehow sent. Anybody an idea?

Comment: Show the code where the exception with the `401` status code is thrown.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin there is no code. It is the standard behaviour from the security mechanism. I just defined the restricted paths in my web.xml

Answer (score 2):

See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html):

> Providers implementing `ExceptionMapper` contract must be either programmatically registered in a JAX-RS runtime or must be annotated with `@Provider` annotation to be automatically discovered by the JAX-RS runtime during a provider scanning phase.

It is part of the JAX-RS runtime and can only catch exceptions thrown in the JAX-RS runtime.

But your HTTP `401` is thrown in your container. In this case you can add an [`error-page`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017571) to your `web.xml`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26429261/5277820.

Comment: nice thanks. now i am able to catch the exception but i am not able to modify the response headers from the servlet. i can´t even change the body. another thing: when i set just a simple html file in my web.xml as error page it works with 404 code but not 401. any idea why?

Comment: I am using wildfly which uses resteasy. I tried to modify the response headers but without any success. I think the response is already committed.

Comment: Did you try the answer from [JBoss Developer](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/248266)?

Comment: that´s sadly just a client workaround and no server solution. Can you think of anything else? I am really lost here.

Comment: Sadly that´s not really an option. So you think there is no standard way? i think i have to post it in the jboss forum once again